# fast implementation of stepwise regression

Tags: python, performance, algorithm

from wikipedia  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepwise_regression

> Forward selection, which involves starting with no variables in the
>   model, testing the addition of each variable using a chosen model
>   comparison criterion, adding the variable (if any) that improves the
>   model the most, and repeating this process until none improves the
>   model.

I think that the implementation of this algorithm is very interesting because it can be seen as a combinatorial version of the hill climbing algorithm where the neighbours function is equivalent to add a variable to the current model.

I have not enough experience to write this algorithm in an optimized way. This is my current implementation:

```
class FSR():

    def __init__(self, n_components):
        self.n_components = n_components


    def cost(self, index):
        lr = LinearRegression().fit(self.x[:, index], self.y)
        hat_y = lr.predict(self.x[:, index])
        e = np.linalg.norm(hat_y - self.y)
        return  e

    def next_step_fsr(self, comp, cand):
        """ given the current components and candidates the function
        return the new components, the new candidates and the new EV"""

        if comp == []:
            er = np.inf
        else:
            er = self.cost(comp)

        for i in range(len(cand)):
            e = cand.popleft()
            comp.append(e)
            new_er = self.cost(comp)
            if new_er < er:
                new_comp = comp.copy()
                new_cand = deque(i for i in cand)
                er = new_er
            comp.pop()
            cand.append(e)
        return new_comp, new_cand, new_er 

    def fsr(self):
        n, p = self.x.shape
        er = []
        comp = []
        cand = deque(range(p))
        for i in range(self.n_components):
            comp, cand, new_er = self.next_step_fsr(comp, cand)
            er.append(new_er)
        return comp, er

    def fit(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.comp_, self.er_ = self.fsr()
```

I would like to know how can I improve the speed of this code.

```
x = np.random.normal(0,1, (100,20))
y = x[:,1] + x[:,2] + np.random.normal(0,.1, 100)
fsr = FSR(n_components=2)
fsr.fit(x,y)
print('selected component = ', fsr.comp_)
```

I want the final code too look not too different from the posted one. This is because I would like to extend the problem to different combinatorial problems with different cost function as well.

I think that the function that should be changed is `next_step_fsr` where given the current selected variables try which one is the best variable to include in the model. In particular I am interested in situation where x has a lot of columns (like 10000). I think that the current bottle  neck  is the line `new_cand = deque(i for i in cand)` where the list of candidates is copied.